# Rendering subscript using DrawText or similar function

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts, rendering, c++builder

The question is simple. How to draw following text into TStringGrid cell?

[image]

Operating system is Windows XP (or Windows Vista or Windows 7). Preferred development environment is C++ Builder 6, but I will accept also solutions for C++ Builder XE of Delphi. Preferred API function is `DrawText`, but if better function exists than this no problem. Font name is `Times New Roman`, font size is 11. Currently I am using this method to render cell content (simplified):

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm_Main::StringGrid_DrawCell(TObject *Sender,
  int ACol, int ARow, TRect &Rect, TGridDrawState State)
{
   TStringGrid *grid = (TStringGrid*)Sender;
   if (grid == NULL) return;

   // 1. BACKGROUND
   grid->Canvas->Brush->Color = grid->Color;
   grid->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);

   // 2. TEXT
   grid->Canvas->Font->Assign(grid->Font);   // Times New Roman, 11pt

   // horizontal centering
   RECT RText = static_cast<RECT>(Rect);
   AnsiString text = grid->Cells[ACol][ARow];
   if (!text.IsEmpty()) {
      int text_len = strlen(text.c_str());
      SIZE size;
      memset(&size, 0, sizeof(SIZE));
      GetTextExtentPoint32(grid->Canvas->Handle, text.c_str(), text_len, &size);
      int offset_x = (Rect.Width() - size.cx) >> 1;
      RText.left += offset_x; RText.right += offset_x;

      // rendering
      DrawText(grid->Canvas->Handle, text.c_str(), text_len, &RText, DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
   }
}
```

Some characters have subscript glyph as special unicode character (for example code 0x2081 is assigned to subscript one) but unfortunately this is not case for capital letter U. Also these characters are not supported by all fonts (for example Times New Roman font doesnt support code range 0x2070 - 209F), see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block) Wikipedia article. I am searching for a more general solution like those implemented by Microsoft Word. MS Word doesn't have problem to render capital letter U as subscript using Times New Roman font.

Comment: Why not render the text in a smaller font size and a few pixels lower than normal?

Comment: Who knows what are the best proportions? The best position? I thought that subscripted chars should be shifted down a bit (which isn't very visible on my example taken directly from MS Word output). Maybe there is some norm to this. I don't know these details. I want the output to look profesional and beautifull.

Comment: @truthseeker: If you want it to look professional, you should use *italics* for (scalar) variables! [This is how it *should* look like!](http://privat.rejbrand.se/phiu120.png)

Comment: I didn't understand your problem... Is it with Unicode characters?

Comment: It doesnt matter if it is Unicode or no. But i prefer Unicode solutions of course. The point of question is "how to render subscript and superscript characters into canvas"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some char to render as superscript you must prefix it with ^. Likewise subscript characters must be prefixed with _.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm_Main::StringGrid_DrawCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow, TRect &Rect, TGridDrawState State)
{
   TStringGrid *grid = (TStringGrid*)Sender;
   if (grid == NULL)
   {
      return;
   }
   WideString wtext = L"φ_U = 120";
   if (wtext.IsEmpty()) return;

   // layout
   SIZE size;
   memset(&size, 0, sizeof(SIZE));
   SSGetTextExtentPoint(grid->Canvas, wtext, size);
   int offset_x = (Rect.Width() - size.cx + 1) >> 1;  // horizontal centering
   RECT RText = static_cast<RECT>(Rect);
   RText.left += offset_x;
   RText.right += offset_x;

   // rendering
   SetBkMode(grid->Canvas->Handle, TRANSPARENT);
   SSDrawText(grid->Canvas, wtext, RText, DT_LEFT);
}

int TForm_Main::SSGetTextExtentPoint(TCanvas *canvas, WideString text, SIZE &size)
{
   // Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12660/Using-Subscripts-and-Superscripts-When-Showing-Tex
   SaveDC(canvas->Handle);

   SIZE sz;
   RECT outRect =
   {0, 0, 0, 0};

   HFONT oldFont;

   LOGFONT lf;
   GetObject(canvas->Font->Handle, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);

   POINT sub, sup, subofs, supofs;

   // Calculate subscript/superscript size and offsets
   bool use_pixel_unit = false;
   if (lf.lfHeight < 0)
   {
      lf.lfHeight    = MulDiv(-lf.lfHeight, 72, GetDeviceCaps(canvas->Handle, LOGPIXELSY));
      use_pixel_unit = true;
   }
   sub.x = lf.lfWidth / 2;
   sup.x = lf.lfWidth / 2;
   sub.y = lf.lfHeight / 3 * 2;
   sup.y = lf.lfHeight / 3 * 2;

   subofs.x = lf.lfWidth / 2;
   supofs.x = lf.lfWidth / 2;
   subofs.y = lf.lfHeight / 6;
   supofs.y = lf.lfHeight / 3;

   lf.lfWidth  = sub.x;
   lf.lfHeight = sub.y;
   if (use_pixel_unit)
   {
      lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(lf.lfHeight, GetDeviceCaps(canvas->Handle, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
   }
   HFONT SubFont;
   SubFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

   lf.lfWidth  = sup.x;
   lf.lfHeight = sup.y;
   HFONT SupFont;
   if (use_pixel_unit)
   {
      lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(lf.lfHeight, GetDeviceCaps(canvas->Handle, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
   }
   SupFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

   WideString temp = text;
   TCHAR c;

   // Calculate the size of the text that needs to be displayed
   do
   {
      int x1       = 1, x2 = 1, x = 1;
      WideString s = "";
      c            = ' ';
      bool bFind   = true;

      // Find the first "^" or "_", indicating the sub- or superscript
      while (bFind)
      {
         x1 = text.Pos(L"^");
         x2 = text.Pos(L"_");
         if ((x1 == 0) && (x2 == 0))
         {
            x = 0;
         }
         else if ((x1 > 0) && (x2 > 0))
         {
            x = min(x1, x2);
         }
         else if (x1 > 0)
         {
            x = x1;
         }
         else
         {
            x = x2;
         }
         if (x == 0)
         {
            bFind = false;
            x     = text.Length() + 1;
         }
         else if (x == text.Length())
         {
            bFind = false;
         }
         else if (text[x] != text[x + 1])
         {
            bFind = false;
            c     = text[x];
         }
         else
         {
         x++;
         }
         s = s + text.SubString(1, x - 1);
         text.Delete(1, min(x, text.Length()));
      }
      sz = canvas->TextExtent(s);
      outRect.right += sz.cx;
      if ((outRect.bottom - outRect.top) < sz.cy)
      {
         outRect.top = outRect.bottom - sz.cy;
      }

      switch (c)
      {
      case '^':
         oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(canvas->Handle, SupFont);
         GetTextExtentPoint32W(canvas->Handle, text.c_bstr(), 1, &sz);
         outRect.right += sz.cx + supofs.x;
         text.Delete(1, 1);
         SelectObject(canvas->Handle, oldFont);
         break;
      case '_':
         oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(canvas->Handle, SubFont);
         GetTextExtentPoint32W(canvas->Handle, text.c_bstr(), 1, &sz);
         outRect.right += sz.cx + subofs.x;
         text.Delete(1, 1);
         SelectObject(canvas->Handle, oldFont);
         break;
      }
   }
   while (c != ' ');

   // Adjust text position
   outRect.bottom += subofs.y;
   outRect.top -= subofs.x;

   size.cx = outRect.right - outRect.left;
   size.cy = outRect.bottom - outRect.top;

   DeleteObject(SubFont);
   DeleteObject(SupFont);
   // Done, restoring the device context
   RestoreDC(canvas->Handle, -1);
   return 0;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int TForm_Main::SSDrawText(TCanvas *canvas, WideString text, RECT &drawRect, int justification)
{
   // Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12660/Using-Subscripts-and-Superscripts-When-Showing-Tex
   SaveDC(canvas->Handle);

   SIZE sz;
   RECT outRect =
   {0, 0, 0, 0};

   HFONT oldFont;
   LOGFONT lf;
   GetObject(canvas->Font->Handle, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);

   POINT sub, sup, subofs, supofs;
   bool contains_subscript   = false;
   bool contains_superscript = false;

   // Calculate subscript/superscript size and offsets
   bool use_pixel_unit = false;
   if (lf.lfHeight < 0)
   {
      lf.lfHeight    = MulDiv(-lf.lfHeight, 72, GetDeviceCaps(canvas->Handle, LOGPIXELSY));
      use_pixel_unit = true;
   }

   sub.x = (lf.lfWidth + 1) >> 1;
   sup.x = (lf.lfWidth + 1) >> 1;
   sub.y = (lf.lfHeight << 1) / 3;
   sup.y = (lf.lfHeight << 1) / 3;
   if (lf.lfHeight == 10)
   {
      sub.y++; // make subscript a little larger
   }

   subofs.x = (lf.lfWidth + 1) >> 1;
   supofs.x = (lf.lfWidth + 1) >> 1;
   subofs.y = (lf.lfHeight + 3) / 6;
   supofs.y = (lf.lfHeight) / 3;

   long sub_shift_down = lf.lfHeight - sub.y;

   lf.lfWidth  = sub.x;
   lf.lfHeight = sub.y;
   if (use_pixel_unit)
   {
      lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(lf.lfHeight, GetDeviceCaps(canvas->Handle, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
   }
   HFONT SubFont;
   SubFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

   lf.lfWidth  = sup.x;
   lf.lfHeight = sup.y;
   if (use_pixel_unit)
   {
      lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(lf.lfHeight, GetDeviceCaps(canvas->Handle, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
   }
   HFONT SupFont;
   SupFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

   WideString temp = text;
   TCHAR c;

   // Calculate the size of the text that needs to be displayed
   do
   {
      int x1       = 1, x2 = 1, x = 1;
      WideString s = "";
      c            = ' ';
      bool bFind   = true;

      // Find the first "^" or "_", indicating the sub- or superscript
      while (bFind)
      {
         x1 = text.Pos(L"^");
         x2 = text.Pos(L"_");
         if ((x1 == 0) && (x2 == 0))
         {
            x = 0;
         }
         else if ((x1 > 0) && (x2 > 0))
         {
            x = min(x1, x2);
         }
         else if (x1 > 0)
         {
            x = x1;
         }
         else
       {
            x = x2;
         }
         if (x == 0)
         {
            bFind = false;
            x     = text.Length() + 1;
         }
         else if (x == text.Length())
         {
            bFind = false;
         }
         else if (text[x] != text[x + 1])
         {
            bFind = false;
            c     = text[x];
         }
         else
         {
            x++;
         }
         s = s + text.SubString(1, x - 1);
         text.Delete(1, min(x, text.Length()));
      }
      sz = canvas->TextExtent(s);
      outRect.right += sz.cx;
      if ((outRect.bottom - outRect.top) < sz.cy)
      {
         outRect.top = outRect.bottom - sz.cy;
      }

      switch (c)
      {
      case '^':
         oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(canvas->Handle, SupFont);
         GetTextExtentPoint32W(canvas->Handle, text.c_bstr(), 1, &sz);
         outRect.right += sz.cx + supofs.x;
         text.Delete(1, 1);
         SelectObject(canvas->Handle, oldFont);
         contains_superscript = true;
         break;
      case '_':
         oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(canvas->Handle, SubFont);
         GetTextExtentPoint32W(canvas->Handle, text.c_bstr(), 1, &sz);
         outRect.right += sz.cx + subofs.x;
       text.Delete(1, 1);
         SelectObject(canvas->Handle, oldFont);
         contains_subscript = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   while (c != ' ');

   // Adjust text position
   if (contains_subscript)
   {
      outRect.bottom += subofs.y;
   }
   if (contains_superscript)
   {
      outRect.top -= supofs.y;
   }
   POINT Origin;
   Origin.y = drawRect.top + (((drawRect.bottom - drawRect.top) - (outRect.bottom - outRect.top) + 1) >> 1);

   switch (justification)
   {
   case DT_CENTER:
     Origin.x = (drawRect.right - drawRect.left) / 2 - (outRect.right - outRect.left) / 2 + drawRect.left;
     break;
   case DT_LEFT:
     Origin.x = drawRect.left;
     break;
   case DT_RIGHT:
     Origin.x = drawRect.right - (outRect.right - outRect.left);
   }

   POINT pnt = Origin;

   text = temp;

   // Draw text
   do
   {
      int x1       = 1, x2 = 1, x = 1;
      WideString s = "";
      c            = ' ';
      bool bFind   = true;

      // Find the first "^" or "_", indicating the sub- or superscript
     while (bFind)
      {
         x  = text.Pos(L"^_");
         x1 = text.Pos(L"^");
         x2 = text.Pos(L"_");
         if ((x1 == 0) && (x2 == 0))
         {
            x = 0;
         }
         else if ((x1 > 0) && (x2 > 0))
         {
            x = min(x1, x2);
         }
         else if (x1 > 0)
         {
            x = x1;
         }
         else
         {
            x = x2;
         }
         if (x == 0)
         {
            bFind = false;
            x     = text.Length() + 1;
         }
         else if (x == text.Length())
         {
            bFind = false;
         }
         else if (text[x] != text[x + 1])
         {
            bFind = false;
            c     = text[x];
         }
         else
         {
            x++;
         }
         s = s + text.SubString(1, x - 1);
         text.Delete(1, min(x, text.Length()));
      }
      // Draw main text
      ExtTextOutW(canvas->Handle, pnt.x, pnt.y, 0, &drawRect, s.c_bstr(), s.Length(), NULL);
      GetTextExtentPoint32W(canvas->Handle, s.c_bstr(), s.Length(), &sz);
     pnt.x += sz.cx;

      // Draw subscript or superscript
      switch (c)
      {
      case '^':
         oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(canvas->Handle, SupFont);
         ExtTextOutW(canvas->Handle, pnt.x + supofs.x, pnt.y - supofs.y, 0, &drawRect, text.c_bstr(), 1, NULL);
         GetTextExtentPoint32W(canvas->Handle, text.c_bstr(), 1, &sz);
         pnt.x += sz.cx + supofs.x;
         text.Delete(1, 1);
         SelectObject(canvas->Handle, oldFont);
         break;
      case '_':
         oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(canvas->Handle, SubFont);
         ExtTextOutW(canvas->Handle, pnt.x + subofs.x, pnt.y + subofs.y + sub_shift_down, 0, &drawRect, text.c_bstr(), 1, NULL);
         GetTextExtentPoint32W(canvas->Handle, text.c_bstr(), 1, &sz);
         pnt.x += sz.cx + subofs.x;
         text.Delete(1, 1);
         SelectObject(canvas->Handle, oldFont);
         break;
      }
   }
   while (c != ' ');

   DeleteObject(SubFont);
   DeleteObject(SupFont);
   // Done, restoring the device context
   RestoreDC(canvas->Handle, -1);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`
    function SSTextLeft(ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; const S: string): integer;

```
var
  i,
  h,
  h3: integer;
  sup,
  sub: boolean;
begin
  with ACanvas, ARect do begin
    h:= textHeight('H');
    h3:= h div 3;
    brush.Style:= bsClear;
    moveTo(Left +1, Top +1);
    i:= 1;
    while i < Length(s) +1 do begin
      if s[i] = '^' then
        begin
          Inc(i);
          font.Height:= MulDiv(font.Height, 8, 10);
          textOut(penPos.X, penPos.Y -h3, s[i]);
          moveTo(penPos.X +1, penPos.Y +h3);
          font.Height:= h;
          Inc(i);
        end
      else if s[i] = '_' then
        begin
          Inc(i);
          font.Height:= MulDiv(font.Height, 8, 10);
          textOut(penPos.X, penPos.Y +h3, s[i]);
          moveTo(penPos.X +1, penPos.Y -h3);
          font.Height:= h;
          Inc(i);
        end
      else
        begin
          textOut(penPos.X, penPos.Y, s[i]);
          Inc(i);
          moveTo(penPos.X +1, penPos.Y);
        end;
    end;//  while
  end;
  sup:= Pos('^', S) > 0;
  sub:= Pos('_', S) > 0;
  if sup and sub then
    result:= MulDiv(h, 5, 3)
  else if sup or sub then
    result:= h +h3
  else
    result:= h;
end;//  SSTextLeft
```

`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.